# What animal does this skeleton belong to?

Tags: species-identification

I was exploring around the outskirts of a local lake this afternoon (central Kentucky, USA), and came across the following skeleton:

[image]
[image]

The length of the remains is somewhere between 9-12".

Can someone tell me what animal this is from, and what part of the body it is?

Comment: It could be the synsacrum from a bird. 9-12" means it would have to be a rather big one. Goose?